# Ruby on Rails: where is init.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am new to rails.I am building my first application. I have to put the following lines in init.rb file:

```
#in init.rb
require ‘active_record’
require ‘simple_search’
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:extend, SimpleSearch::ClassMethods)
```

could you tell me what is the location of init.rb file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to the add the above lines to vendor/plugins/simply_searchable/init.rb

https://gist.github.com/362823

Restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: when i try to install the plug in from git. I get this error:

Comment: .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- simple_search (LoadError)

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in `config/environment/init.rb` or `config/initializers/init.rb`

Comment: I get this name error: undefined local variable or method `acts_as_simply_searchable' for #<Class:0x000000036e5750>